# Trouble calling `str.len` on a pandas object column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a string column called `title` and I want to convert each row's entry to that string's length.  So "abcd" would be converted to 4, etc.

I'm doing this:

```
result_df['title'] = result_df['title'].str.len()
```

But unfortunately, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

which seems to imply that I don't actually have strings in my column...

How should I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have a mixture or incorrect dtypes, try `result_df['title'] = result_df['title'].astype(str).str.len()`, this will cast the entire column to `str` if it can before calling `str.len`

Comment: I believe you already converted it, hence why you now get the error.  Either that, or your column has both strings and numeric values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're either trying to convert the whole column to str and not the values or have mixed types in the column. Try:

```
result_df['title'] = result_df['title'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)))
```

Comment: No, this isn't the OP's problem, they probably have incorrect or mixed dtypes

Comment: No it won't work if the OP had for instance timestamp/datetime, numeric values. At the moment we don't know what the real problem is

Answer (score 2):

If your column has strings and numeric data, you can first convert everything to strings and then get the length.

```
result_df['title'] = result_df['title'].astype(str).str.len()
```

To find the data that is not a string/unicode, try this:

```
result_df.loc[result_df['title'].apply(
    lambda x: not isinstance(x, (str, unicode))), 'title']
```